# Kind &Humble request to all : Please don't forget reviewing "First questions"

Tags: discussion

In the early times I had not enough reputation to have my questions going through directly, I remember having been very grateful to those who had took time to review them, this enabling my questions to go through.

Holidays ? Moderators on strike ? Else ? Nevermind.
I tried my best these two last days and discovered that some were waiting for 5 days and the span of my skills is not large enough for me to juge all. Not to say that my contribution is only worth for a fifth of the job.

So, please, remember our beginnings and kindly review a couple of them.

Comment: Note that new posts don't wait for anything, they are visible on the site as soon as they are posted. I mean, they _do_ go through directly, they're just also added to the new post review queue for review, but that doesn't affect the visibility of the post in any way as far as I know.

Comment: Thx for the info @terdon. I had apparently missed something. I ergo close this discussion.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because of terdon's contribution in comments. I apologize for the noise.

Comment: And yet, its a nice reminder for us all to do our civic duty ;-)